# Clonezilla cloning to smaller disk

Tags: gparted, lvm, clonezilla

I have an SSD disk with LVM volumes (used for Proxmox) that i want to move to smaller SSD. The original disk is 525 GB large, the new drive has 500 GB. I have shrinked the physical volume and the partition on the original drive, hoping a device-device clone in Clonezilla will go trough.

Below you can see how GParted shows the allocated space.
[Screenshot of GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGxWV.png)

Afterwards I have tried to run clonezilla with the option `-icds` while keeping the source partition table but i still get a disk too small error.

My second attempt was to go with the option 'Resize partitional table proportionally. ', but here i got an error while copying the boot partition saying disk is too small:
[Screenshot of Partclone error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS47x.png)

Any ideas how to procees are welcome

Comment: Is it an option to use `dd` instead?

Comment: tried dd as well, took a few hours to get trough, but for some reason the partition table on the target disk is not showing up. i have also tried to restore the partition form the source disk but it fails and manually i cant create it either. on the source disk , the first partition starts at sector 34, but on the target disk i cant sent anything lower than 2048...

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/574262/454022

Comment: thanks, the trick wish `sgdisk ` worked. i have now successfully migrated the disk, but there is one more issue, the original drive had 512 byte sectors, the new one has 4096 bytes advanced format, so i think my partitions are misaligned. so far it seems that the easiest way to solve to use clonezilla and clone the drive a different disk using partclone, then cloning it back. as the disk has now the correct size there should be no problem with the size